# Choose a random function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python 3.5 is it possible to have a list of definitions and have a function choose and call that random definition? I am asking this because all of the docs I have seen for random just says about generating a random pseudo number.

Comment: What is a definition?

Comment: something that can be called from within that file/class e.g.
e.g. `def intro():
print("hello")
intro()`
Obviously with proper indentations and what not

Comment: [random.choice(seq)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: add code in question, not in comment.

Comment: @M213081: Please edit your question, and include all the essential pieces of information. We have absolutely no idea what you are thinking unless you explain it well..

Comment: So you mean a function? Functions are first-class objects in Python. You can put in them in any container and choose randomly from there.

Comment: @M213081  `seq` can be list with function names

Comment: Re: "… all of the docs I have seen for random just says about generating a random pseudo number" — The `random` module is included in the standard library and one can read its [fine documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random). There I see the [description of the `choice` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice): "_`random.choice(seq)` — — Return a random element from the non-empty sequence `seq`. If `seq` is empty, raises `IndexError`._".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def foo(): print('foo')
>>> def bar(): print('bar')
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice([foo, bar])
<function foo at 0x10499d668>
>>> choice([foo, bar])()
foo
>>> choice([foo, bar])()
bar
>>> choice([foo, bar])()
foo
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.